# React Native Config Not Picking Up .env Changes

Tags: react-native, config, react-native-config

My react-native-config isn't picking up changes in my .env

Only when I uninstall and then reinstall does react-native-config pick up the changes in my .env file.

Comment: Did you figure out what the issue was? This is only happening in XCode, if I build through terminal works fine.

Comment: take a look at this [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75473225/react-native-config-not-working-empty-config-in-both-os/77409920#77409920) it worked for me