# react-native-config not working (Empty Config in both OS)

Tags: react-native, environment-variables, react-native-config

I'm really struggling with what seems like a very primitive error. I have installed react-native-config and when console.logging the Config object it returns `{}`.

The problem occurs both on android and iOS and it doesn't seem to be a linking issue because (even though RN 71.3 doesn't require manual linking) when following the steps to link manually on android I got an error saying RNCConfigPackage already linked.

This is a simplified version of my code:

```
import Config from 'react-native-config';

console.log(Config);
```

And this is what my .env file looks like:

```
REACT_APP_STAGE=development
TEST=ThisIsATest
ANOTHER_TEST=ThisIsAnotherTest
```

### Debugging attempts

I have already tried:

- Running gradlew clean and pod install (even though it's not a platform specific issue)
- Run with `ENVFILE=.env react-native run-android` to hard code the env file

I understand that this is very limited information in order to debug the issue but any direction and help is appreciated including any approach you would follow to debug.

**EDIT**: The Config appeared in the end but is very late to update, [an issue more people seem to be facing](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config/issues/591), I have used react-native-dotenv instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fix tested on

- `"react-native": "0.72.6"`
- `"react-native-config": "^1.5.1"`

**Android**

add to your `app/build.gradle`

```
project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
        debug: ".env",
        release: ".env",
]

apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"

...

android {
...

    defaultConfig {
...
      resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.yourApp.packageName"
    }
```

**iOS**

Go to `Product` > `Scheme` > `Edit Scheme...`

in the left panel `Build` > `pre-actions`
add a `new run script action` and add the code below ( to generate the `GeneratedDotEnv.m` )

```
xcodebuild -project "${SRCROOT}/../node_modules/react-native-config/ios/ReactNativeConfig.xcodeproj"
```

then in your `Pod` file add this line under your *target*

```
pod 'react-native-config', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-config'
```

and last step :
`cd ios && pod install`